# What are the most popular crypto currencies after Bitcoin?

Tags: alternatives, currencies

I am trying to determine which crypto currencies are the most popular with the assumption that Bitcoin is the most popular one.

This question is up to different interpretations because "most popular" can be viewed many different ways and that is why I am here asking this question.  Most popular could be based on the most real world use, the most media interest, the most valuable, or the most number of people mining or the most processing power used in mining.

I want to know your opinion based on solid facts of the current state of crypto currencies.  It could be that another crypto currency is more popular than Bitcoin based on your rank, and I doubt that, but that is why I want the help from experts here.

Comment: *"opinion based on solid facts"* - why not simply ask for the facts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an online store accepts another crypto-currency appart from Bitcoin, you can be sure 90% of the time it'll be Litecoin (most accept just Bitcoin as of now). It's the one that has the 2nd biggest market capitalization and market depth as well. As to what could be the 3rd most popular, that's difficult.

"Popularity" is difficult to measure directly, but you can use value in fiat as a proxy. Right now, several crypto-coins are valuable about 1 US dollar or more: just go to [cryptsy](http://cryptsy.com) or to [coinwarz](http://coinwarz.com)and check the market prices (given in bitcoins). Given current prices of bitcoin in USD anything more valuable than one milli-bitcoin is worth aprox. a dollar, a lot of coins are worth more.

Another proxy you can take is how frequently you see ads of people asking for donations or offering their services in exchange of that currency - that way, you'll see humble dogecoin being asked/offered a lot, where as protoshares/quarks are almost never asked for in spite of their value. Other coins worth more than a dollar (like prime, name or PPC) would take the lead here based on this metric.

Comment: Stop the presses! 42-coin is about 800 BTC on cryptsy!!! How can that be? It's far more valuable than bitcoin itself, with practically no use except speculation! Are people being deluged into buying because of the "only 42 coins will ever exist"? And some people worried about bitcoin's top of 21 million...

Answer (score 3):

google news on my phone had an article yesterday.   LiteCoin, DogeCoin, Quark, NameCoin, PeerCoin      ( Dogecoin is a less serious to take)

Bitcoin is king, will it be unseated... not in 2014.  Litecoin is clearly 2nd,  there is no other second choice for 2014 ,  Perhaps PeerCoin, Namecoin, WorldCoin or something with surpass Litecoin in the future, but to overtake bitcoin when there is Overstock.com accepting it,  ATM's being made for Bitcoin, it is the king.

Alt coins are fun to mine if you have a good AMD GPU etc.. , but you have to weigh the cost of electricity, or be into flipping coins for better ones on an exchange.

I have mined for several.  Bought several, flipped several.....  it is obviously a high risk.  To me is it a safer gamble than the lottery or casino's.

There is a ranking chart of the difficulty of mining various coins.  More they are mined the more difficult.  A friend of mine has the open rigs and has 3-4 computers in crates with like 10-12  AMD R9 280x GPU cards, and those are like 400-500 bucks each GPU.     You can easily mine for "fun" if you wish, Coinye is like a super easy coin to mine. I don't think it is traded/ has value yet or if ever.

Ripple you can buy for 0.02 cents , go to Wells Fargo and buy it through them...

Comment: Coinye? ppfff... the only exchange that traded it, 0daycoins, apparently is a scam... anyway, they were exchanging at about 5 satoshis, so it's a waste of electricity (only mineable for fun and to piss off that one rapper, no more). As of now, Dogecoins and Digitalcoins are slightly more profitable than mining Litecoin directly, but you have to have good timing and stategy at the exchanes. As you said, PPC, Name, prime or quark could reach/surpass litecoin, few others seem capable

Comment: Coinye is funny, cracks me up.   NorrisCoin was stopped.  Chuck Norris is much more powerful than Kanye!

Comment: Bitcoin is still top,  but Ethereum and some others are pretty darn good

Answer (score 1):

On http://coinmarketcap.com/ you can see most altcoins ranked by market cap. You can also sort by volume. This should give you a clear idea of what coins are currently popular.

Comment: A better site for this is http://coingecko.com/ which tracks things like reddit, github activity, etc, which seems better suited to popularity than raw marketcap (a measure which badly fails for coins with highly concentrated ownership, or high proportion of coins stuck out of the market, for whatever reason).